# How to Connect angular from phone to pc under same network

Tags: jhipster

I need to connect from my phone to laptop where jhipster application running.

The phone and laptop are under same network.

I run these command in the laptop:

- mvnw
- npm start

then from my phone I go to the address http://{laptop local address}:9000 but the site is not reachbale

I changed the command npm start --host 0:0:0:0 but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try using ngrok it will be the solution for your problem if you are on same network and want to run web app and test it on other device.
Here is the reference
https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with/node-js/